# Do Gmail have block email, domain support in user mailboxes through APIs?

Tags: gmail-api

I am looking for block email/domain support in Gmail APIs, but i am not able to find any in this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides. Does this operation is supported by Gmail APIs

The use case I am trying to cover is to block a list of malicious email addresses in users mailbox via APIs. So if received email matches this list, it will automatically be moved to junk / delete email.

The same use case is supported by Office 365, you can create a rule in user mailbox and add all those malicious email addresses into the rule and set action on the rule e.g move to junk / delete email via API. Also you can later update this list to add/ remove email addresses.

Comment: Can you be more clear what you mean by block email/domain.   The Gmail api lets you access data in a users Gmail account.

Comment: @DalmTo The use case i am trying to cover is to block a list of malicious email addresses in users mailbox via APIs. So if received email matches this list, it will automatically be moved to junk / delete email. Hope things are clear now.
The same use case is supported by Office 365, you can create a rule in user mailbox and add all those malicious email addresses into the rule and set action on the rule e.g move to junk / delete email via API. Also you can later update this list to add/ remove email addresses.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a [filter](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters)?   Good question BTW I actually had to look it up 

Answer (score 0):

#### You can do this in the Admin Console

1. In your Google Admin console (at admin.google.com)...
2. Go to Apps > Google Workspace > Gmail > Spam, Phishing and Malware.
3. To apply the setting to everyone, leave the top organizational unit selected. Otherwise, select a child organizational unit.
4. Point to Blocked senders and choose an option:
5. To edit an existing setting, click Edit.
6. For a new setting, click Configure or Add anotherand thenenter a unique description.
7. Click Use existing or create a new one.
8. Choose an option:

   - To create a list, under Create new list, enter a name for the list and then click Create.
   - To use an existing list as your blocked sender list, under Available lists, click the list name.
9. Point to the list name, click Edit (>) and then Add (+).
10. Enter one or more email addresses or domain names. Separate each entry with a comma or space.
11. Click Save.

#### Reference

- [Block messages from an email address or domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2364632)

#### Edit

There are many options for blocking from Organizational Units, to the whole Domain. There is also Spam filter functionality that is customizable.

However there is no API for these settings. If you feel like you need you should file a feature request using this template:

> #### [Admin SDK Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102)

Comment: does this block email / domain in all users mailboxes? also do we have api support for that ?

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer to address those questions